# SQL - select values from two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, group-by

I have got a problem with selecting values from two different tables. Tables below:

Material:

```
MaterialID | MaterialName
-------------------------
1111111    | Material1
2222222    | Material2
3333333    | Material3
```

Stock:

```
MaterialID | Location | Quantity
---------------------------------
1111111    | LocA     | 10
1111111    | LocB     | 20
2222222    | LocC     | 15
2222222    | LocD     | 10
```

My SQL query below:

```
SELECT
    [Material].[MaterialName] as 'Material Name',
    custom.quantity as 'Total Quantity',
FROM
    [Material]
    inner join (
        SELECT
            [MaterialId] as 'Materialcode',
            SUM([Quantity]) as 'Quantity'
        from
            [Stock]
        group by
        [MaterialId]
    ) custom 
    on 
        custom.Materialcode = [Material].[MaterialId]
```

The result is:

```
Material Name | Total Quantity
------------------------------
Material1     | 30
Material2     | 25
```

The problem is that in the result there is no information about Material3 (I know that the quantity is equal to 0 as it`s not in Stock table, but I need a result that will show all of the materials - like below:

```
Material Name | Total Quantity
------------------------------
Material1     | 30
Material2     | 25 
Material3     | 0
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Use a `left join` and `nvl(custom.quantity) as 'Total Quantity'` in your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `left join` and aggregate:

```
select m.materialName, coalesce(sum(s.quantity), 0) total_quantity
from material m
left join stock s on s.materialID = m.materialID
group by m.materialID, m.materialName
```

You may also aggregate, then `left join` (that was your original attempt, you just need to change the join type).

Actually, you might as well use a correlated subquery - with an index on `stock(materialID, quantity)`, this may be an efficient solution (and you don't need `coalesce()` here):

```
select 
    m.materialName,
    (select sum(quantity) from stock s where s.materialID = m.materialID) total_quantity
from material m
```

Another way to express this is to use a lateral join:

```
select m.materialName, s.total_quantity
from material m
outer apply (select sum(quantity) total_quantity from stock s where s.materialID = m.materialID) s
```